# Add a Public Key to an Ubuntu EC2 server via SSH

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, public-key

I’m trying to add my friend’s public key to my Ubuntu EC2 server **via the ssh terminal** but I can’t find the file that I paste the key in. Can anybody explain where the file is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, note that is best to create a specific user for your friend instead of just adding his key to the default ec2-user on aws, [as I stated here](https://serverfault.com/questions/866654/aws-ec2-instance-access-best-practices/866658#866658)

Add his public key on .ssh/authorized_keys under his home directory. Remember that you have to create the .ssh dir if it does not exist and authorized_keys too. Permission for the .ssh directory are 700 and for the authorized_keys file 600

So, for example

```
cd .ssh
```

or, only if it dos not exist

```
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
```

then

```
nano authorized_keys
```

edit your file by putting your public ssh key and when finished

```
chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

For editing you have various solutions, this is one of the simplest, human wise.

Comment: I got into the .ssh directory with `cd ~/.ssh` but I couldn’t get into `cd authorized_keys`, it said it did not exist. Can you tell me the commands to use to create `authorized_keys`?

Comment: authorized key is a file. i am updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

add the public key in the file (/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add his key, the best method is to have him send you his public key, and then run from your workstation:

```
ssh-copy-id -i friendkey.pub ec2-user@ubuntuserver
```

This will automatically ssh into the machine, and properly append it to the file. Advantages are lowering the risk of screwing up the file format or permissions.

With that said, I agree with Federico that you really should create another user.